# Qt set default locale and print longDayName

Tags: qt, locale

I need to set the default locale of my app to german and print the first long dayname 'Montag' but I am getting 'Monday'

```
QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::German, QLocale::Germany));
qDebug() << QDate::longDayName(QDate::currentDate().dayOfWeek());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#longDayName) of `QDate::longDayName()`:

> The day names will be localized according to the system's locale settings, i.e. using [`QLocale::system()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#system).

This is not the default locale you have set. In order to use the [default one](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#setDefault), you need to construct a `QLocale` object with no arguments. After that you can call [`QLocale::dayName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#dayName) to get the localized name of the day (according to the default locale you have set):

```
QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::German, QLocale::Germany));
qDebug() << QLocale().dayName(QDate::currentDate().dayOfWeek());
```

---

As [noted by peppe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426114/qt-set-default-locale-and-print-longdayname/40426801?noredirect=1#comment68111170_40426801), one should always use `QLocale` for locale-dependent conversions. As of Qt 6 `QDate`/`QTime` will be using the C locale.

Comment: Casual observation: the fact that QDate/QTime use the system locale is a mistake that we need to carry around in Qt 5. In Qt 6 they will always use the C locale. So always use QLocale for all locale-dependent conversions.